# Android Volley request/response duration problem

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I'm using Android Volley library for HTTP requests.
Intermittently a request takes more time than Volley indicates.
For example:

[image]

According to Volley the request took:

```
X-Android-Received-Millis - X-Android-Sent-Millis  =  1603832510411 - 1603832508914 = about 1.5 seconds.
According to logcat it took:
14:01:50.664 - 14:01:38.818 = about 12 seconds
```

It does take 12 seconds for the UI results to show up.
What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Check what time it took after you get the response and then processing the data and showing the UI also

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my question, what could be causing this delay in UI response after request already returned. There is nothing specific in the log for these 11 seconds. This happens maybe once in an hour or two, the rest of the time the same request takes the same 1 second and UI is updated right away, taking about 1- 1.5 seconds all together.